# Selecting specific table cells in Selenium web driver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract the information from a link from a page that is structured as such:

```
...

<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">$725,000</td>

<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> Available</td>

*<td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="/washington">


 Washington Street Studios
<br>1410 Washington Street SW<br>Albany, Oregon, 97321
</a>
</td>*

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">15</td>

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">8.49%</td>

<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">$48,333</td>

</tr>
```

I tried targeting elements with attribute 'align = left' and iterating over it but that didn't work out. If anybody could help me locate the element `<a href = "/washington">` (multiple tags like these within the same page) with selenium I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post more `tr` rows so we can get a clear picture of where the desired links are located? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use lxml instead, if it is just to process hxml...

It would be helpful if you're more specific, but you can try this if you are traversing links in a webpage..

```
from lxml.html import parse

pdoc = parse(url_of_webpage)
doc = pdoc.getroot()
list_of_links = [i[2] for i in  doc.iterlinks()]
```

list_of_links will look like ['/en/images/logo_com.gif', 'http://www.brand.com/', '/en/images/logo.gif']

doc.iterlinks() will look for all links such as form, img, a-tags and yield lists containing Element object containing the tag, the type of tag (form, a or img), the url and a number, so the line

```
list_of_links = [i[2] for i in  doc.iterlinks()]
```

simply grab the url and returns as a separate list.

Note that the retrieved url is *relative*. As in you will see urls like

```
'/en/images/logo_com.gif'
```

instead of

```
'http://somedomain.com/en/images/logo_com.gif'
```

if you want to have the latter kind of url, add the code

```
from lxml.html import parse
pdoc = parse(url_of_webpage)
doc = pdoc.getroot()
doc.make_links_absolute()     #  add this line
list_of_links = [i[2] for i in  doc.iterlinks()]
```

If you are processing the url one by one, then simply modify the code to something like

```
for i in iterlinks():
    url = i[2]
    # some processing here with url...
```

Finally, if for some reason you need selenium to come in to get the webpage content, then simply add the following to the beginning

```
from selenium import webdriver
from StringIO import StringIO

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
doc = parse(StringIO(browser.page_source)).getroot()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what we have provided at the moment, there is a `table` and you have the desired links in a specific column. There are no "data-oriented" attributes to rely on, but using column index to locate the links looks good enough:

```
for row in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#myid tr"):
    cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

    print(cells[2].text)  # put a correct index here
```